# Error in importing "asammdf" in Robotframework

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframework-ide

i have written a custom Library in python, which imports a package named "asammdf". But, when i import my custom Library in Robot code, it shows error in importing "asammdf" in python. It says: "Error in File *.robot. Importing test Library *.py failed. Import Error: DLL load failed: the specified module could not be found."

"asammdf" package is available in one of the PYTHONPATH it mentions during executions.

Can someone please help me doing this and let me know, what have i done wrong?
My python File (trialRobot.py):

```
import asammdf
...
...
...
```

My robot file (TC1.robot):

```
*** Settings ***
Library trialRobot.py

*** Test Cases ***
TC1
   DO THIS
   DO THAT
```

The error it shows is:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'G:\AutomationRobotFramework\RobotAutomationFramework\TC1.robot': Im
porting test library 'G:\AutomationRobotFramework\RobotAutomationFramework\trialRobot.py' fa
iled: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\AutomationRobotFramework\RobotAutomationFramework\trialRobot.py", line 1, in <mod
ule>
    import asammdf
  File "g:\automationrobotframework\venv\lib\site-packages\asammdf\__init__.py", line 15, in
 <module>
    from .blocks.mdf_v2 import MDF2
  File "g:\automationrobotframework\venv\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\mdf_v2.py", line 4
, in <module>
    from .mdf_v3 import MDF3
  File "g:\automationrobotframework\venv\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\mdf_v3.py", line 4
4, in <module>
    from ..signal import Signal
  File "g:\automationrobotframework\venv\lib\site-packages\asammdf\signal.py", line 9, in <m
odule>
    from .blocks.utils import MdfException, extract_cncomment_xml, SignalSource
  File "g:\automationrobotframework\venv\lib\site-packages\asammdf\blocks\utils.py", line 27
, in <module>
    from cchardet import detect
  File "g:\automationrobotframework\venv\lib\site-packages\cchardet\__init__.py", line 1, in
 <module>
    from cchardet import _cchardet

PYTHONPATH:
  G:\AutomationRobotFramework\venv\Scripts\robot.exe
  C:\Program Files\Python37\python37.zip
  C:\Program Files\Python37\DLLs
  C:\Program Files\Python37\lib
  C:\Program Files\Python37
  g:\automationrobotframework\venv
  g:\automationrobotframework\venv\lib\site-packages
  g:\automationrobotframework\venv\lib\site-packages\pip-19.0.3-py3.7.egg
```

But, the asammdf package is installed in python using pip without any name or location conflict. It is installed only once and in the folder, where pip installs by default.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install cchardet 2.1.5

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the absolute path or relative path to the example.py file.

so like,

```
*** Settings ***
Library C:/SomeFolder/example.py
```

or

```
*** Settings ***
Library ../folder/example.py
```

Comment: (1/n) Thanks for the reply. But, my question is regarding the libraries installed in python using pip or something similar. Not the ones, which i am writing as a custom script.

So,
I am creating a custom Library named "Example.py". In example.py, i am importing some pre-installed python module named "asammdf" (just like numpy, pandas, etc.)

when i try to import example.py in my robot file, it gives error saying, asammdf not found. But, it is installed. In i import numpy, it works fine. I think it is an issue of relative paths given in "asammdf".

Comment: (2/n) In "asammdf", there are some imports like "from .abc import xyz" and "..abc import xyz". I think, the Robot file is getting confused about the locations of this. Because, it doesn't work for all the python modules having this kind of relative imports. Another example for this is "keras". In Keras also, this is the same situation.

Comment: (3/n) Can you please tell me, how to handle this? Because, all the modules, which i want to use, are installed using pip and also unique. There is no name conflict. They are installed only once and also all in the same location, where python install them by default.

Comment: (4/n) I have edited the question with the exact error it shows while execution. You can check and try to help me, if you can.